# "Chrome" would like to paste from ... how can I get this question to stop popping up every time I copy/paste?

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, copy-paste

I have a MBP and iPad, I often copy from one to the other and I use Chrome as the iPad browser.

When I copy a link on the MBP, go to the iPad -> Chrome and paste it, I get the question:

"Chrome" would like to paste from "Your Name Here"

Do you want to allow this?

Don't allow Paste

Allow Paste

I thought this was taken care of when you answer yes to "trust this computer?" but seems not the case.

Q: How can I get this to stop asking me this every time I copy/paste something?

Comment: I think this is a known bug on iOS 16, which was supposed to be fixed in a recent update (at least for iPhones it has)? The message should only pop up once for every app, and remember your selection. I'd recommend you update to the latest OS or if you have already but it still happens, maybe Apple hasn't got round to fixing it for the iPad version of iOS yet.

Comment: It was not fixed on iPad.